# Inconsistency in BigQuery Data Ingestion on Streaming Error

Tags: google-cloud-platform

While streaming data to BigQuery, we are facing some inconsistency in data ingested when making https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/tabledata/insertAll requests using BigQuery Java library.

Some of the batches fail with error code: **backendError**, while some requests **time-out** with exception stacktrace: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/18aea1c72f8d22d2ea1792bb2ffd6139

For batches which have failed, we have observed 3 different kinds of behaviours related to ingested data:

1. All records in that batch fail to be ingested into BigQuery
2. Only some of the records fail to be ingested into BigQuery
3. All records successfully gets ingested into BigQuery​ in-spite of the​ thrown error

**Our questions are:**

1. How can we distinguish between these 3 cases.
2. For case 2, how can we handle partially ingested data, i.e., which records from that batch should be retried?
3. For case 3, if all records were successfully ingested, why is error thrown at all?
   Thanks in advance...

Comment: *CLOSED**CLOSED*

Answer (score 1):

The error you provided in the Gist is [`java.net.SocketTimeoutException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/SocketTimeoutException.html)`: Read timed out`, which is thrown by the Java `HttpClient` when a socket operation times out locally. It is not directly thrown by the BigQuery service (though could be indirectly caused by the connection terminating abruptly due to some server side issue).

A [`backendError`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/troubleshooting-errors#errortable) is different - this will indicate a (usually) temporary server failure or some other error condition that occurs remotely, which the BigQuery service was able to signal while still keeping the connection open.

Both errors can potentially occur before, in the middle of, or after record ingestion, which is why you sometimes see no records, partial records, or all records being written. BigQuery [is not transactional](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/streaming-data-into-bigquery#usecases), so partial inserts happen as a result of errors.

So to answer your questions:

1. There isn't a simple way to distinguish between the three cases, other than querying for data that should have been written and checking for its existence. Since streaming inserts are done in batches, its much simpler to just backoff and retry on the failed batch, potentially overwriting any existing data. This is one reason the [`insertId`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/tabledata/insertAll) field is provided - to avoid duplication and [ensure data consistency](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/streaming-data-into-bigquery#dataconsistency) when retrying inserts.
2. Continuing from above, you should handle all cases the same way for both `SocketTimeoutException` and `backendError`, which is to always retry the failed batch and use `insertId` to avoid duplication.
3. Also expanding on 1., any timeout or system issue can still occur even after the data has been written, especially in the case of `SocketTimeoutException`.

Comment: Regarding 1st point of using insertId, we cannot rely on that as it is not specified for *how long* BigQuery remembers it, hence, if retries after exponential back-off goes beyond that *un-specified* time till which BigQuery remembers insertId, data duplicity will surely happen. Relevant text in first 2 lines: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/streaming-data-into-bigquery#dataconsistency. I don't see how can *insertId* be useful in presence of unspecified remember time, and retries

Comment: Have you tried it, and found that it does not work? BigQuery remembers the insertId for at least one minute - that is 60 seconds between each time it successfully gets the insertId for a request. Backoff and retry usually starts a 2 seconds, and capping your max backoff to a low enough value should be sufficient to avoid most issues.

Comment: In any case, this is the only method of preventing duplication automatic to BigQuery at present, and the docs even go on to mention that automatic deduplication may not always be possible. Your other alternative is to later query inserted data if any insert errors occurred and manually remove duplicates.

Comment: 60 seconds might be a large amount of time for these operations, but, it's not guaranteed that retries would not exceed that 60 seconds. Hence, even if we consider insertIds during retries, we anyhow will still have to perform other set of operations of querying by insertId, and inserting that data only which has not already been streamed. Thus, making insertId entirely useless. Anyways, we have already handled this case. Closing it down, as I don't see a solution coming out here